# What is wrong with my if statement 'if x + y = z'

Tags: ruby

I am trying to evaluate if a selected item meats a requirement. I am trying to evaluate the result of `nominal + x` against `required`.

I am using the following code:

```
if @weight.nominal + x = required
              weights << @weight.id
end
```

However, it adds `nominal + x` together. Why is that, and how do I do what I want?

Comment: The `=` should be `==` for comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pavan said in the comment, your conditional might be wrong. It should be `==` instead of `=`. `=` is the assignment.

```
if @weight.nominal + x == required ... end
```

Here what happens "behind the scene" with your original code:

1. `required` is assigned to `x`.
2. Add x to `@weight.nominal`  (`@weight.nominal + x`)
3. Evaluate the result from step 2, which is always true.
4. Execute the code within `if` block, which is `weights << @weight.id`

Eventually, your `x`'s value is lost, it will take `required` value instead and your conditional is useless since it always true.